# How to overwrite a Timer in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 buttons(rotate and reverse). When either button is ON the other is deactivated as both cannot be on at the same time. When On button is turned OFF, it gives the disabled button 10 seconds before back to Normal.

My question is How can I stop the 10sec timer if I was to  hit ON(same button turned off) before the 10 second timer. Example, If I turn ON rotate then OFF(this starts 10 second timer for Reverse) but if decide to turn rotate ON again my timer to reverse button is still counting. How can I stop the timer, so that if I turn OFF again it can start new 10sec?

\\

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from threading import Timer
from time import sleep

reverse_motor = True
rotate_motor = True


def hp30():
    global rotate_motor
    # Turn ON 30hp Motor
    if rotate_motor:
        rotate_motor = False
        motor30hp.config(activebackground=motor30hp.cget('background'))
        reverseButton["state"] = DISABLED
        motor30hp["text"] = "ON"
        motor30hp["bg"] = "green"
        print("30hp Motor ON")
        motor30hp.config(activebackground=motor30hp.cget('background'))
    else:
        # Turn OFF 30hp Motor
        rotate_motor = True
        motor30hp["text"] = "OFF"
        motor30hp["bg"] = "red"
        print("30hp Motor OFF")
        motor30hp.config(activebackground=motor30hp.cget('background'))
        tim01 = Timer(10, normal_reverse)
        tim01.start()
        print("Reverse 10 sec Timer On")


def reverse():
    global reverse_motor
    if reverse_motor:
        reverse_motor = False
        motor30hp["state"] = DISABLED
        print("Rotate Disabled")
        reverseButton.config(activebackground=reverseButton.cget('background'))
        print("Reverse Motor ON")
        reverseButton["text"] = "ON"
        reverseButton["bg"] = "green"
    else:
        reverse_motor = True
        reverseButton["text"] = "OFF"
        reverseButton["bg"] = "red"
        reverseButton.config(activebackground=reverseButton.cget('background'))
        print("Reverse Motor OFF")
        timer = Timer(10, normal_hp30)
        timer.start()
        print("Rotate 10 sec Timer On")

def normal_hp30():
    motor30hp.config(state='normal')
    print("Rotate Enabled")


def normal_reverse():
    reverseButton.config(state='normal')
    print("Reverse Enabled")


root = Tk()
root.title("SOTS Remote")
root.geometry('400x150+0+0')
root.configure(background="black")

myFont = font.Font(family='Times', size=30, weight='bold')

#-------------------------------lABELS--------------------------------------------------------
root.label2 = Label(root, text="Rotate", font=myFont, fg="white", bg="black")
root.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W", padx=25, pady=2)

root.label3 = Label(root, text="Reverse", font=myFont, fg="white", bg="black", padx=30)
root.label3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NW", pady=2)
#----------------------------------------buttons--------------------------------------------------




reverseButton = Button(root, text="OFF", font=myFont, height=1, width=7, bg='dodgerblue',
                       command=reverse, relief=RIDGE,bd=5)
reverseButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NW")
reverseButton.config(activebackground=reverseButton.cget('background'))

motor30hp = Button(root, text="OFF", bg='red', relief=RIDGE, bd=5, font=myFont,
                   command=hp30, height=1, width=7)
motor30hp.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
motor30hp.config(activebackground=motor30hp.cget('background'))

root.mainloop()
```

\\

Comment: You would need to save your `Timer` objects somewhere that is accessible later (global variables, perhaps), so that you can call `.cancel()` on them.  But note that interacting with Tkinter widgets from separate threads (as your timer callbacks will be) tends to not work very well.  You might be better off using Tkinter's `.after()` method for scheduling these delayed function calls, and `.after_cancel()` to stop them.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to keep an `activeTimer` counter that increments for each time a timer is created, and decremented by the callback function.  As long as the count is nonzero return immediately from the callback without taking action.  When the timer is zero, the last timer has elapsed, so you can do the function.